# mp4 not playing in Chrome or Firefox, but in Safari

Tags: html, video, mp4

I've a very strange problem. The background video on [this site](http://www.neomotion.studio/home) is playing in Safari but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Adding the attribute "controls" via the dev tools I see the correct video duration. But it seems that the video is transparent at all.

The same problem appears when you open the video link directly:
[neomotionstudio-reel-2019.mp4](http://www.neomotion.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/neomotionstudio-reel-2019.mp4)

Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Your file is huge (67M for 52 sec !) and seem to have some broken attributes. After converting it via [this site](https://www.ps2pdf.com/compress-mp4) I was able to play it on Chrome

Comment: The current codec for your video is H.265 which is not supported **yet** by Chome and Firefox change it to H.264 and it will works [More informations](https://caniuse.com/#feat=hevc)

Comment: @Core972 thanks. That was the problem! Much appreciation for the very quick response!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a video format problem. Not every browser knows how to decode every video format, you can read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) on MDN to learn more.

An easy solution is re-encoding your video. Here is an example using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i http://www.neomotion.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/neomotionstudio-reel-2019.mp4 video.mp4
```

It should give you a file working in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That won't work. Firefox requires very specific encoding specs to actually work where as Chrome and Edge are more lax. OP would need to look into all these quirks before having ffmpeg blindly reencode the video (e.g. Firefox requires yuvj420p, it won't work with yuv420p).

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved: The motion designer has exported the video in HEVC/H.265 instead of H.264 video format which isn't supported by Firefox and Chrome.